# Unable to chat after the 20 reputation on stack overflow

Tags: support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How long does it take for chat profiles to update?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95423/how-long-does-it-take-for-chat-profiles-to-update)

I have got the 27 reputation and for chat its require the 20 reputation but still i am getting the message that

> its require 20 reputation

Comment: How long ago did you reach 27 rep? It may take a little while to sync your rep up with the chat site.

Comment: @JoshMein sir, my account is 1 hour old

Comment: The chat site most likely doesn't have an updated count of your rep. If you give it some time, I am sure it will resolve itself.

Comment: @JoshMein it mean a site like stackoverflow a world most famous type of its type is slow ?

Comment: @hek - actually its super-duper-fast partly because of such caching methods that are used through out the network. Triggering a [reputation recalculation](http://stackoverflow.com/reputation) might just nudge the system enough to update. Just scroll to the bottom of that link at hit the button.

Comment: @Lix thank you lix its working. could you make this answer so in future if any other user got the situation  like me they doesn't need to ask a new question

Comment: It's interesting, though, I wonder if Lix's method actually made a difference, or if it just took so long for you to post this question, wait for Lix's comment and follow his advice that the cache updated naturally.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Part of the reason that the Stack Exchange network of sites operate in such a super-duper-zippy-fast manner is because of [caching methods](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121716/10-rep-missing-intermittently-from-account-overview). There are many places where data is cached - badges, [reputation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CjdOP.jpg), etc...

In this case, you could attempt to nudge the system just enough for it to recalculate your "permissions" with regard to using the chat features.

Head on over to the [Reputation breakdown page](https://stackoverflow.com/reputation), take a look at all the pretty numbers and scroll to the bottom of the page where you'll find a "Trigger reputation recalc" button. Press it.

[image]

[There](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134759/order-by-activity-broken) [are](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127664/bug-in-flair-of-stack-overflow) [many](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127664/bug-in-flair-of-stack-overflow) [posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69401/why-is-my-flair-not-updated-with-my-actual-reputation-score) [on](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/853/how-aggressive-is-the-caching-used) [meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/853/how-aggressive-is-the-caching-used) [where](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130856/why-are-my-sede-results-inaccurate-obsolete-incorrect-outdated) [the answer/solution](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60403/how-does-stack-overflow-do-caching) [turned out to be cache related](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69164/does-stack-overflow-use-caching-and-if-so-how).

Comment: +1 for that three arrows with freedom.